# Minimal layout with header, footer, Left Menu, Content, RightMenu on Bootstrap 4-5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Help to make a minimal layout with **header**, **footer**, **LeftMenu**, **Content**, **RightMenu** on **Bootstrap 4-5**.
The width of **LeftMenu** + **Content** + **RightMenu** is similar to the width of the main block of the current site(html forum.io ).
In other words, not the entire width of the browser, but in the center.    Maybe there is some practice for the width of such elements?
**LeftMenu** - bound to the left edge of the container.
**RightMenu** - bound to the right edge of the container.

For example...

Analog in the picture.
[image]

I try, everything jumps ...

**Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Настройка viewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>...</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle JS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Контент страницы -->  
<div class="container sm ">
<header  class="s-topbar ps-fixed t0 l0 js-top-bar bg-primary text-white">
  <div class="container-fluid p-3">
    HEADER
  </div>
</header>
<section class="position-relative">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 a1 bg-danger text-white w-3 ">A1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 a2 bg-warning text-dark">A2</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 a3 bg-success text-white">A3</div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<footer class="fixed-bottom"> 
  <div class="container-fluid p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white" >
    FOOTER
  </div>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/User65659/m4svktd8/1/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a simple layout like this using Bootstrap 4 or 5.

[image]

I think this is the style you wanted, you can change height and padding and all that stuff.

**View:** https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/full/RwQZERj

```css
.header{
  background-color:#2f2f2f;
color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  height:70px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.left{
  background-color:#F55353;
  height:250px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.middle{
  background-color:#FEB139;
  height:250px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.right{
 background-color:#00B4D8;
  height:250px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center; 
}

.footer{
  background-color:royalblue;
  text-align:center;
  height:70px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header col-12">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 left">
  <h4>left</h4>
  </div>
    <div class="col-6 middle">
      <h4>middle</h4>
    </div>
  <div class="col-3 right">
    <h4>right</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer col-12">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to add an additional solution to your answer that uses only bootstrap and does not use CSS?
Is it possible?

Comment: it will work even if you apply no css

Comment: **1.** I'm not good at terminology.
I did without CSS - https://jsfiddle.net/User65659/gqvhfzu6/9/

**2.** Could you make sure that the layout does not occupy the entire width of the browser, but is located in the center.
And the height of the layout should fill the entire screen (I'm talking about this just in case... you have it done.)
The left and right were fixed widths.
The middle is stretched
Analog - stackoverflow.com

Comment: The things are actually present there but if you don't apply CSS it won't look like you want.
You need to use some CSS to make it look like the HTML layout, like CSS's border property, background-color, and padding to look it much better. 

You said you wanted the content at the center I have done it:
https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/full/RwQZERj

Comment: Sorry... I understood... If it is impossible without css, then let it be with css.
Could you please refine it further?
It is necessary that the `header` is at the top, the `footer` is at the bottom, and the central part is stretched. 
I remind you: the width of the layout should not stretch to the entire screen.

Comment: done @eusataf https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/full/RwQZERj

Comment: Add this solution in the answer...
 Thanks a lot...

Comment: Could you please correct your decision again.
**Expectations:** 
-**1.**  press the `Left` block to the left border;
-**2.**   press the `Right` block to the right border;
-**3.**   the `Middle` block should be pressed against the `Left` and `Right'. This has already been done. There is no need to correct anything on this point;

Comment: Picture - https://i.ibb.co/3B4mj4Y/05-08-2022-16-43-102.png

Comment: done @eusataf https://codepen.io/nisoojadhav/full/RwQZERj